# iOS: App freezes and gives me an SIGABRT in xcode

Tags: ios, sigabrt

When I start my app everything goes well. But if I close it, I mean really close it, and then opens it again it shows me the last open view and the app is totally freezed and xcode shows an SIGABRT error.

I have done so much, it's not that easy to just step backwards and see where it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you use git or some other version control system ?

Comment: I normally use git, but haven't commit anything in a while. This app is just for learning and I guess I've learned my lesson.

Comment: Tough lesson, but try to get into the habit of committing after every successful iteration of `make changes`/`debug`/`test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehm ok I might have done a noobie misstake...

I disconnected my phone from my computer (with the app totally closed) opened it and closed it again. Now when I open it, everything works. I guess you can't do that when running from xcode... he he...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an Exception Breakpoint in XCode? If something's wrong in your execution (possibly as a result of stored state from the previous execution that is now being loaded?), then you'll be able to see exactly where an exception happened before the program received the SIGABRT.